# Como se puede lograr un diseño tipo clip path |-/-/-/-/-| con imagenes y que s autoajusten al ancho de pantalla?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un problema para diseñar una seccion de mi pagina web. La seccion debe contener 5 imagenes pegadas y en una sola fila, algo como |-/-/-/-/-|.

Cabe indicar que las imágenes de fondo deben estar derechas, no torcidos y centradas.

Estoy intentando diseñarlo con clip-path, pero no logro juntarlas.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fotos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content-img">
        <div class="content-img--1">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img--2">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img--3">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img--4">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img--5">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Y este es el css, cada imagen tiene un fondo y es mas cada una debe ser un enlace a otras paginas:

```
.content-img {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.content-img--1 {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://www.proandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Fondos-De-Pantalla-HD.jpg?width=1200&enable=upscale");
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20% 0, 15% 100%, 0 100%);
    background: cover;
}

.content-img--2 {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://www.gizlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Fondos-de-pantalla-HD-portada.jpg");
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 40% 0, 35% 100%, 15% 100%);
    background: cover;
}

.content-img--3 {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://www.proandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Fondos-De-Pantalla-HD.jpg?width=1200&enable=upscale");
    clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 60% 0, 55% 100%, 35% 100%);
    background: cover;
}

.content-img--4 {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://www.gizlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Fondos-de-pantalla-HD-portada.jpg");
    clip-path: polygon(60% 0, 80% 0, 75% 100%, 55% 100%);
    background: cover;
}

.content-img--5 {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://www.proandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Fondos-De-Pantalla-HD.jpg?width=1200&enable=upscale");
    clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 75% 100%);
    background: cover;
}
```

Espero ser lo mas claro y me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es necesario que agregues tu **HTML5** y  **CSS** de las secciones de las imágenes, para que podamos ayudarte. Sin código es imposible ver y hallar el problema, terminará cerrada tu pregunta.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 2):

Creo que más o menos entendí el estilo que quieres aquí te muestro un pequeño ejemplo. Si vas al url de cada imagen de das de cuenta que cada una tiene un tamaño diferente.

```css
.conteiner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 34vh;
    width: 100vh;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    margin-left: 50vh;
    margin-right: 50vh;
}

.content-img {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
.content-img img{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fotos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="https://www.gizlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Fondos-de-pantalla-HD-portada.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3yl9rywMG_rs8CXRYrioEBusvykKOj2vRG6449Qh1F0oDLnkwnTyj47To77OAqeqkQ=w2048-h3482-rw" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQuKxTm3L2nCDKX9RiwZ0qp01v_NVrymbCSng&usqp=CAU" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="https://www.proandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Fondos-De-Pantalla-HD.jpg?width=1200&enable=upscale" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content-img">
            <img src="https://fondosmil.com/fondo/13637.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que buscas esta en la porpiedad  `transform: skewX(-10deg);` dentro de la clase  `.content-img`
Espero haberte ayudado, si tienes alguna duda, con gusto te la responderé.

Comment: por favor explica tu código, las explicaciones ayudan mucho :)

Comment: Si, es que cuando iba a editar no me dejaba. Pero el punto es que la propiedad transform: skewX(-10deg); es quien te da el estilo skew

Comment: ok pero para próximas respuestas trata de explicar todo lo posible